# change comment structure in buddypress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I try to change  default comment structure of buddy press with my own plugin and add some custom edit . for that i found we should use `wp_list_comments` and in callback function . i use below example function:

```
function my_blog_comments( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;

    if ( 'pingback' == $comment->comment_type )
        return false;

    if ( 1 == $depth )
        $avatar_size = 50;
    else
        $avatar_size = 25;
     ...
 }
wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'my_blog_comments', 'type' => 'comment' ) );
```

but cant show any change on comment structure what's wrong in my code

Answer (score 1):

wp_list_comments goes in your template file.

Comment: want change structure of comment from plugin . want crete a plugin that limit last comment show for example shows last 3 comment only and dont show replay with depth . can do that with a custom plugin ? or just change in theme ?